# How to install package with pip that has access to an R script

Tags: python, r, pip, setuptools, conda

#### The issue

I need to create a python package that will have access to an R script and make it pip installable

#### The setup:

My package structure is as follows

```
foo/  
  setup.py  
  foo/
    foo.R
```

The contents of `setup.py` are:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='foo',
    packages=find_packages(),
    scripts=['foo/foo.R'],
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

and the contents of `foo.R` are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

R.version
```

I am installing this package with:
`pip install -e .`

When I look at the R script that is installed it is no longer an R script so when it is called it is being run as python and therefore fails

`$ cat $(which foo.R)` to view the contents of the file

#### What I am expecting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

R.version
```

#### What I get:

```
#!/Users/jc33/miniconda3/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-DEV-SCRIPT: 'foo==0.0.0','foo.R'
__requires__ = 'foo==0.0.0'
__import__('pkg_resources').require('foo==0.0.0')
__file__ = '/Users/jc33/Desktop/foo/foo/foo.R'
exec(compile(open(__file__).read(), __file__, 'exec'))
```

#### additional scope

This is a very contrived example that was created for the sole purpose of finding a solution, not to debate the merits of locating an R script using setuptools. For a bit more information I am creating a more complex python package similar to [this](https://github.com/qiime2/q2-dada2) that will need to call R at some point this is done with `subprocess.run` however I believe that is out of the scope of this question

```
Python=='3.5.2'
setuptools=='27.2.0'
pip=='10.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your R script is insufficiently unlike Python.

If you were to put some R code that causes a syntax error such as a leading `.` or any usage of `$` or `foo[[0]]` you would find that setuptools (but really distutils+easy_install) does not produce the `develop` wrapper.

The source that controls the script wrapper can be found [here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/1252d1b3b34261acd6c8051c4fe97f206a7118b7/setuptools/command/easy_install.py#L797-L805). It tests with [`is_python_script`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/1252d1b3b34261acd6c8051c4fe97f206a7118b7/setuptools/command/easy_install.py#L1931) which calls [`is_python`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/1252d1b3b34261acd6c8051c4fe97f206a7118b7/setuptools/command/easy_install.py#L1906). This in turn just compiles the file. A successful compile returns True and causes easy_install to make the wrapper script, and unsuccessful one returns False and the file is simply copied verbatim (which is what you want).

Answer (score 1):

`scripts` are for **Python** scripts. If you want to install something
that isn't Python code at all you need to treat that as data. In
`setuptools` it's called [`package_data`](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#package-data):

```
setup(
    name='foo',
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={
        'foo': ['foo.R'],
    },
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

The file will be installed as `foo/foo.R` and you can find it from a module in `foo/`, let's say it's `foo/foo.py`. First thing in `foo.py` is to find its directory and then call `foo.R`:

```
import os, subprocess
foo_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
subprocess.check_call(['r', os.path.join(foo_dir, 'foo.R')])
```

PS. Please note the code is supposed to be in a module in `foo/` directory. For a different directory it has to manipulate with `__file__` in a different way.

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to what I was thinking. I was basing my code on the package I linked to above which _does_ include the R scripts in `scripts` and works without issue (This is not to say it is the best way however!). Following your example, how would I then call the R script? In otherwords where would I find this script?

Comment: `scripts` can be used for non-Python as well: http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-scripts-keyword-argument

Comment: @johnchase I extended the answer.

Comment: Should be `os.path.dirname(foo.__file__)`?

Comment: No, this code is supposed to be in `foo/foo.py` and Python set `__file__` to the full path of the file. Well, it could be full path to `foo.pyc` but after `dirname()` it is irrelevant.

Comment: @phd got it, this is useful even though it wasn't exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior for "editable" installs. From the [setuptools docs](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html):

> In addition, the develop command creates wrapper scripts in the target script directory that will run your in-development scripts after ensuring that all your install_requires packages are available on sys.path.

`pip install -e` isn't quite the same as `python setup.py develop`, but it's intended to be very close. I believe the [implementation](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/10.0.1/src/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py#L875) is a thin wrapper around `python setup.py develop`.